# Quotients of the groups of higher unit group of $p$-adic field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Here in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_field) link, the $n^{th}$ higher unit group of non-Archimedean field $F$ is defined by $$ U^{(n)}=\{u \in \mathcal{O}^{*}~|~ u \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ \mathfrak{m}^n \}=1+\mathfrak{m}^n \subset \mathcal{O}^{*},$$ where $n \geq 1$. The group $U^{(1)}$ is the group of principal units and $U^{(0)}:=\mathcal{O}^{*}$. Then we have the tower,
$$ \mathcal{O}^{*} \supseteq U^{(1)} \supseteq U^{(2)} \supseteq \cdots $$
Consider the following quotients $$ \mathcal{O}^{*} /U^{(n)} \cong (\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}^n)^{*} \ \text{and} \ U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \approx \mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{m}.$$
**My question:**

Whether or not the above two quotients are subsets/subgroups of $\mathcal{O}^{*}$ ?

i.e., whether or not $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \subset \mathcal{O}^{*}$ and $\mathcal{O}^{*}/U^{(n)} \subset \mathcal{O}^{*}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: If the residue characteristic is large enough, using the $p$-adic logarithm, $\mathcal O^* \cong (\mathcal O/\mathfrak m)^* \times U^{(1)}\cong  (\mathcal O/\mathfrak m)^* \times \mathcal O$. The right hand group is torsion free, so the answer to both questions is no so long as $n > 1$. (In general, $\mathcal O^*$ has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to $\mathcal O$, so the answer is still no if $n$ is large enough)

Comment: @Mathmo123, Do we have, at least, $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \subset \mathcal{O}$ ?  Also, is $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \cap \mathcal{O}^{*} \neq \emptyset $  ?

Comment: When you originally asked whether some things "are" subgroups of ..., I thought you meant "are isomorphic to subgroups of ...". But your comment and edited question seem to say you really are asking about sets (an intersection only really makes sense if the sets are contained in a common superset), to which the answer is that as sets, a priori those quotients are trivially *disjoint* from $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{O^*}$.

Comment: Then again, even if you mean "up to isomorphism", if your field is $p$-adic, the answer to your question about $\subset \mathcal O$ is found immediately from (and almost literally included in) @Mathmo123's first comment.

Comment: @Mathmo123, $\mathcal{O}$ is bigger than $\mathcal{O}^{*}$, i.e., $\mathcal{O}^*=\mathcal{O}-\mathfrak{m}$. So it is strange that a a finite index subgroup $A$, say, of $\mathcal{O}^{*}$ satisfies $A \cong \mathcal{O}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I am thinking the quotients as subgroups.  So $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)}$ can not include any $p$-adic integer. i.e.,  $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \cap \mathcal{O} =\emptyset$, because $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)}$ is torsion group with all torsion elements but $\mathcal{O}$ is torsion free. Is that all ?