# Is $\mathcal{O}_K^{*} /U^{(n)} \cap \bar{\mathfrak{m}}_K \neq \emptyset $?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Consider the $p$-adic field $K \supset \mathbb{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_K$ whose $n^{th}$ higher unit group is defined by $$ U^{(n)}=\{u \in \mathcal{O}_K^{*}~|~ u \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ \mathfrak{m}_K^n \}=1+\mathfrak{m}_K^n \subset \mathcal{O}_K^{*},$$ where $n \geq 1$. The group $U^{(1)}$ is the group of principal units and $U^{(0)}:=\mathcal{O}_K^{*}$. Then we have the tower,
$$ \mathcal{O}_K^{*} \supseteq U^{(1)} \supseteq U^{(2)} \supseteq \cdots $$
Consider the following quotients $$ \mathcal{O}_K^{*} /U^{(n)} \cong (\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_K^n)^{*} \ \text{and} \ U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \cong \mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{m}_K.$$

Let $\bar K$ be the algebraic closure of $K$ with maximal ideal $\bar{\mathfrak{m}}_K$ be its maximal ideal.

Both the quotients $\mathcal{O}_K^{*} /U^{(n)}$ and $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)}$ has torsion elements and hence $\mathcal{O}_K^{*} /U^{(n)} \cap \mathcal{O}_K=\emptyset$ as well as $U^{(n)}/U^{(n+1)} \cap \mathcal{O}_K=\emptyset$.

**My question:**

Is $\mathcal{O}_K^{*} /U^{(n)} \cap \bar{\mathfrak{m}}_K \neq \emptyset $ ?

Thanks

Comment: As with your previous question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4179071/96384, I am not even sure if what you are asking makes sense. On a formal set level, a quotient just *cannot* be contained in the set (or any subset of the set) that it is a quotient of. If on the other hand you are asking about embeddings or more general group homomorphisms from the quotient to the respective sets, then why is it not clear that the additive group $\bar{\mathfrak m}_K$ has no torsion and hence there is no non-trivial embedding of a torsion group into it either?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, I just want to know, whether or not they can have common elements either treating them as groups or treating them as just sets.

Comment: But would you say $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/12$ "have common elements", "treating them as groups or treating them as just sets"? I have tried to explain as best as I can that I find the question either nonsensical or trivial. If you do not understand what I'm saying, I'm sorry.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg, sorry. But here we have the closure $\bar{\mathfrak{m}}_K$ and thats what confused me. Anyway thanks